# Metal for Linux; How to create a shader compiler, given a GPU document

Tags: c++, linux, shader, metal

Is there any open source project trying to implement Apple's Metal shading language specification https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf for `Linux`? I am a `C++` habitat; not liking `Vulkan` much.

Does Apple's Metal compiler compiles the shader into an intermediate representation like `SPIR-V`. I even don't know much about `SPIR-V`. I even don't know much about `GPU` hardware implementation but I know how `SIMD` is achieved in GPUs for various transforms. Does it have some instruction set like `CPU`? Is SPIR-V different from an instruction set?

I got my MacBook's i5-5257u processor architecture document; I want to implement Metal shading language specification for Linux; I have just written a software 3D graphics renderer.

An answer with brief on various GPU interface components that should go into a `Fragment`, `Vertex`, `Geometry` shader compiler should fit here.

Comment: This question reads as "I don't know anything about GPUs, how do I create a graphics API?", which is both a very ambitious project (even for experienced developers) and too broad for SO. It would require you to write your own compiler, an entire API and the drivers for each GPU you want to support

Comment: Alternatively you could try doing the reverse of what MoltenVk (https://moltengl.com/moltenvk/) does, which is a direct mapping of the Vulkan API onto Metal, but that is too broad for SO as well (and also a very big project in itself)

Comment: Also note that your title and first paragraph are mixing two things: Shader languages vs Graphics APIs. Metal Shading Language is only the shading language (as opposed to the Metal Graphics API), while Vulkan is a Graphics API that does not specify which shading language has to be used. If your goal is to use a different shading language for Vulkan that is a smaller project (though still too broad for SO), see e.g.: Microsofts HLSL to SPIR-V compiler https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler

Comment: Yes I want to implement Metal API as well so that the program compiles on both the platforms. Does Metal compiler compiles to an intermediate code like DirectX12 n Vulkan?

Comment: Can I use LLVM compiler to produce GPU opcode

Comment: Yes, Metal compiles to an intermediate representation, just like Vulkan and Direct3D. However the compilation of that to GPU instructions happens in the driver itself, so you'd need to write your own GPU drivers in addition to the API